# Is there a saying like "I don't believe myself"?

Tags: grammar, expressions

Could I say "I don't believe myself"? Like I am saying some facts that are so unbelievable that I am not sure if they are even correct. Or where nobody else believes something that I am saying and I then I am starting to doubt myself.

Comment: I don't think there is a term for this specific scenario, you can just say something like, "I'm not so sure about this, but I think I heard that these facts are true." Just add doubt to your comment.

Answer (score 1):

**"I can't believe what I'm saying, but ... "**

is a fairly common (200 000 hits on a Google search) 'comment-clause', but the speaker usually knows full well and is in full control of what they're saying, and this is a further hedged version of "You're not going to like / accept / believe this, but ...".

**"I'm speaking off the top of my head here; ..."**

is sometimes used before a statement that one is not sure is totally reliable (but where one is *trying* to be factual).

Comment: With an added variation of "I can't believe I'm saying this, but..."

Answer (score 0):

Answering the last past of the question:

> Nobody else believes something that I am saying and I then I am starting to doubt myself.

The phrase '**lone voice**' is given in [MacMillan Dictionary](https://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/british/lone-voice) as

> the only person with a specific opinion

---

Also the phrase '**voice in the wilderness**' is given in [MacMillan Dictionary](https://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/british/a-voice-in-the-wilderness?q=voice+in+the+wilderness) as

> someone whose suggestions are ignored